# Simple asymmetric ARCH vs asymmetric ARCH

Tags: time-series, garch, arch

I am working with GARCH models. As I try to familiarize myself with Stata's options I have run into a number of questions I am having problems answering.

What is the difference between SAARCH and AARCH?

If EGARCH and AARCH are both tools to deal with asymmetry, why prefer one vs the other?